# File system query

Tags: filesystems

Is there an easy way to query data in file system?
We are storing data in File system (instead of database)
Is there a way to query the content of the file system?
The data in the file system is stored in xml format.
since the data is growing day by day we are finding it difficult to query the content of the files in the file system.
Can anyone suggest what could be the tool/method to query the data in the existing file system?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific by what you mean by querying the data. File names? sizes? paths? contents?

Comment: As a part of data analysis we require to query the contents of the files in the file system.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can write an application to provide a query interface, parse the query and then go and search through the file system.

But seeing that a database is perfect for this kind of thing, why don't you migrate to a database.  You can use/write a FileWatcher to load the data into a database as it's written to the file system (so you don't have to change the system that's creating the files), and make your job a whole lot easier.

?